# optional parameter in Angular service

Tags: angular-services, optional-parameters

I have this service in my Angular Project

```
getActividades(usuarioId: number, año: number, mes: number, quincena?: number): Observable<IActividad[]> {
return this.http.get<IActividad[]>(`${this.urlWebApi}/empleados/${usuarioId}/actividades?year=${año}&mes=${mes}&quincena=${quincena}`)
  .pipe(
    //tap(data => console.log('Listado Empleados', JSON.stringify(data))),
    tap(data => console.log('Listado actividades', data)),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}

where the last parameter quincena is optional, but this call gets me an error

[image]

Any idea, please?